# Emacs Orgmode table $> References does not work

Tags: emacs, org-mode

**GNU Emacs 24.4.1 org-mode**

Here is an org-mode table

```
#+TBLNAME: revenue
| /       | <        |           | <        |                  | <    |       |         |        |            |           |      |       |        |       |         |       |
| Product | Year_SUM | Month_SUM | Platform | Platform_SUM     | adwo | AdMob | adChina | adSage | appfigures | appdriver | coco | Domob | Dianru | Limei | guohead | youmi |
|         |          |           |          |                  |      |       |         |        |            |           |      |       |        |       |         |       |
|---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------------+------+-------+---------+--------+------------+-----------+------+-------+--------+-------+---------+-------|
| Jan     |          |           | iOS      | #ERROR           | 1    |     1 |       1 |      1 |          1 |         1 |    1 |     1 |      1 |     1 |       1 |     1 |
|         |          |           | Android  | =vsum($6..$>);NE |      |     1 |         |      1 |            |         1 |      |     1 |        |     1 |         |     1 |
|---------+----------+-----------+----------+------------------+------+-------+---------+--------+------------+-----------+------+-------+--------+-------+---------+-------|
|         |          |           |          |                  |      |       |         |        |            |           |      |       |        |       |         |       |
#+TBLFM: $5=vsum($6..$>);NE
```

As you see ,the formula `$5=vsum($6..$>);NE` can't be calculated! Here is  debug info:

```
Substitution history of formula
Orig:   vsum($6..$>)
$xyz->  vsum($6..$>)
@r$c->  vsum($6..$>)
$1->    vsum((0)..$>)
        --------^
Error:  Expected `)'
```

But if I replace the formula with `$5=vsum($6..$17)` and then it works ,I can't figure out where is the problem?

I need some help ,appreciate it!

Comment: Works OK on orgmode 8.2.6 (results in 12 and 6 in column 5)

Comment: Appriciate your tips, inspire me that maybe I should try another org-mode version